# How to deploy WETH contract in a hardhat test

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

I have a WETH contract that I want to deploy on my hardhat test network. Source of the WETH contract can be found [here](https://etherscan.io/address/0xc02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc2#code#L11).

When I run the following hardhat test:

```
const { expect } = require("chai");
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

describe("testing", function () {
  it("Should work", async function () {
    const Weth = ethers.getContractFactory("WETH")
    const weth = await Weth.deploy()
    await weth.deployed()

    expect(true).to.equal(true);
  });
});
```

I receive the following error:

```
  testing
    1) Should work


  0 passing (725ms)
  1 failing

  1) testing
       Should work:
     TypeError: Weth.deploy is not a function
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/test.js:22:29)
      at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:439:21)
```

Why is it saying I can't deploy the contract? Is the solidity version so old Hardhat can't deploy it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to await the getContractFactory
2. .deployed() is, iirc, only in web3js (you can remove it here)
3. double check you contract name (« WETH », case sensitive) if it’s not solving it

```
const { expect } = require("chai");
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

describe("testing", function () {
  it("Should work", async function () {
    const Weth = await ethers.getContractFactory("WETH")
    const weth = await Weth.deploy()

    expect(await weth.symbol()).to.equal(“WETH”);
  });
 });
```

Comment: Wow! Using `await` worked!! I wonder why we have to use await here. In other contracts I've used await without fail. Is it because await may succeed before the next line of code is read and would cause await to pass?

Comment: Yes that is true. You could maybe read about async and await in javascript to understand this better. Looks great so far!